# why can't my class friend function access a protected member with namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces

This is something that normally works, but my use of namespaces is messing it up.

Take this code:

.h:

```
class FetchRecord
{
   friend KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r );
protected:
   int mId;
};
```

.cpp:

```
KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r )
{
   os << r.mId;
   return os;
}
```

This works fine. But if I do:

.h:

```
namespace Blah
{
    class FetchRecord
    {
       friend KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r );
    protected:
       int mId;
    };
}
```

.cpp:

```
using namespace Blah;

KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r )
{
   os << r.mId;
   return os;
}
```

Then the friend decl seems ignored:

```
src/fetch.cpp:153:25: error: 'mId' is a protected member of 'Blah::FetchRecord'
```

I can tell probably what is happening - the function in the .cpp does not match up with the function in the friend decl. How do you solve this?

@Update: Two correct answers below right now. Thanks. Tested and works. But I hate having to put my operator<< function in the Blah namespace. It would be cleaner if the full prototype for the function were:

```
KxStream& operator<<( KxStream&, Blah::FetchRecord& );
```

That is, if I could somehow forward declare that friend function outside of the namespace Blah. And I found a way:

```
namespace Blah
{
   class FetchRecord;
}

KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, Blah::FetchRecord& r );

namespace Blah
{
   class FetchRecord
   {
      friend KxStream& ::operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r );
   };
}
```

You have to get pendantically explicit. Note the "::" in the friend decl of operator<<.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you define `operator<<` in global namespace, it's unrelated to what you declared in .h file. You should define it in `namespace Blah`:

```
namespace Blah {
    KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r )
    {
       os << r.mId;
       return os;
    }
}
```

Update: if you want `operator<<` to belong to global namespace (which is strange, because thanks to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) it will work even without `using namespace Blah`), you can write the following in .h file, and leave .cpp file as it is:

```
namespace Blah
{
    class FetchRecord;
}

KxStream& operator<<( KxStream& os, Blah::FetchRecord& r );

namespace Blah
{
    class FetchRecord
    {
       friend KxStream& ::operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r );
       //              ^^^^
    protected:
       int mId;
    };
}
```

Comment: Correct and works. But I wish there was another way. I don't like that my operator<< function be in the Blah namespace.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista why exactly don't you like it?

Comment: Lol. Exactly what I just posted in the update to my question.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista not exactly!

Comment: Yeah. My actual working code is just like your example. My update above I flubbed the placement of the "::". Also the reason to keep the operator<< in global scope is because I want the operator to work even when not "using namespace Blah".

Comment: @RafaelBaptista thanks to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) it will work without `using namespace Blah`, see [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14d7d3ea94a99682)

Answer (score 1):

Despite `using namespace Blah`, you still need to qualify the name when defining the function because `Blah` was the namespace in which it was declared. It should be:

```
KxStream& Blah::operator<<( KxStream& os, FetchRecord& r )
```

Comment: Correct and works. But I wish there was another way. I don't like that my operator<< function be in the Blah namespace.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Then declare it outside the namespace before you declare it as a friend.

Comment: Can't find a way to do that that isn't very ugly. E.g. the normal forward decls and gcc treats as two different functions.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista The function is in the global namespace so the friend decl needs to be `friend [..] ::operator<<(...)`. Notice the `::` indicating the global namespace.